# How do you use a font from your file system HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a font file that I want to use called Gotham Light Regular. How would you access that file to change the font? Below is what I have now, but it isn't working.

```css
.name{
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

```html
<style>
        @font-face {
        font-family: myFirstFont;
        src: url(fonts/Gotham Light Regular/Gotham Light Regular.otf);
        }
</style>

<div class= "name">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2>Bye</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put font files to web accessible location and put proper CSS for it.

You can download this font from internet (e.g. [cufonfonts](https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/gotham)) or find your font files on computer ([example](https://www.lifewire.com/locate-font-files-1074150)).

Then put CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GothamLight';
    src: url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.otf') format('opentype'),
         url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.eot?iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/fonts/Gotham-Light.svg#gothamlight') format('svg');
}


body {
   font-family: GothamLight;
}
```